# getting IndexoutofBounds exception on using view pager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-imageview, image-gallery

I am a newbie in android app development and I am following this tutorial to create an image gallery.
https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/03/20/get-all-images-from-gallery-in-android-programmatically/.
Its working perfectly but now I want to display images in view pager for being able to display images by swiping left/right.I am using an adapter for doing it but I guess I am doing something wrong because it gives IndexoutOfBounds exception. Can anyone help me with that ? Am I giving incorrect path for images in the adapter ?

**TouchImageAdapter.java**:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class TouchImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    String filename;
    ArrayList<Model_images> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
    int position,int_position;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView img = new ImageView(container.getContext());
        img.setImageDrawable(getImageFromSdCard(filename));
        container.addView(img, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        return img;
    }

    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }


    public Drawable getImageFromSdCard(String imageName) {
        Drawable d = null;
        try {
            String path = al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position)
                    + "/";
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path + "/" + imageName
                    + ".jpeg");
            d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),bitmap);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return d;

    }
}
```

LOGCAT :

```
09-15 18:15:34.791 13080-13080/com.example.dell_1.Myapp3 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.dell_1.Myapp3, PID: 13080
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
 at com.example.dell_1.myapp3.ImageViewer.TouchImageAdapter.getImageFromSdCard(TouchImageAdapter.java:53)
 at com.example.dell_1.myapp3.ImageViewer.TouchImageAdapter.instantiateItem(TouchImageAdapter.java:30)
 at com.example.dell_1.myapp3.ImageViewer.TouchImageAdapter.instantiateItem(TouchImageAdapter.java:16)
 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1034)
 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1182)
 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
 at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6126)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1117)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:642)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6126)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
 at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6126)
 at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6126)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6126)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6126)
 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
 at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:687)
 at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2303)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1390)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1639)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1278)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6357)
 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(position)

the position in here is not defined

Comment: In the getItemCount methos why you don't return the al_menu instance count?

Comment: You hardcoded the value of getcount() method change your return value of  getcount() method to total size by using size(); method

Comment: where to define position ? @YamenNassif

Comment: Have you geting `al_menu` or list of images in this adapter ?

Comment: I did it @ZaighamRaza , still its giving me same exception . I replaced it using al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size()

Comment: I replaced return 1; by return al_menu.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().size():, still same probllem @MichaelAlexanderMontero

Comment: I want the list of images in a specific folder like "WhatsApp Images" in this adapter @UpendraShah, like a normal image gallery in android

Comment: @RedViper check the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `IndexOutOfBounds` because your position field is not defined:
adjust your code to the following:

```
public Drawable getImageFromSdCard(String imageName,int position) {
```

and

```
img.setImageDrawable(getImageFromSdCard(filename,position));
```

this should fix this issue

## edit

based on comments another issue with the adapter will be the count

change your code like this:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return al_menu.getSize();
}
```

## edit 2

Don't forget to populate your list 
1- add constructor public

```
TouchImageAdapter(Context context,List<Model_images> alMenu){
    this.al_menu = alMenu;
    this.context = context;
}
```

2- When you call your constructor in the activity apply this code:

```
TouchImageAdapter myAdapter = new TouchImageAdapter(getActivity(),yourList);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that has fixed the exception but my main problem is to make viewpager work, it should display the next image on swiping. How do I get that working ?

Comment: then you need to get the correct count will update the answer

Comment: @RedViper i should not do this, but since you are new here, usually thanks is welcomed but you should consider also upvoting, accepting and/or 
 downvote answers for the reference.

Comment: ohh okay, thanks for telling me, I dont have reputation for upvoting , but I have accepted your answer

Comment: and it would be great if you could  help me to make the viewpager working because still its not working. I am not able to swipe images. I dont know what am I doing wrong now

Comment: i have udpated the answer

Answer (score 0):

you don't initialize al_menu list. al_menu is empty therefore you are getting indexoutofexception. Also your count method returns 1 even if you initialize list with more than one item you will always get first of the list.

Comment: even if its empty its initialized which means the IndexOutOfBounds exception wont occur

Comment: @Yamen Nassif You can try below code in https://www.compilejava.net/
if your list is empty and you try to get first element it will throw indexoutofexception

import java.util.ArrayList;
public class HelloWorld
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<String> al_menu = new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.print(al_menu.get(0));
  }
}

Comment: If you do it this then Exception will happen but adapter doesnt work this way, since the list is empty the position will never be called and it will be hanlded inside of all of the adapter

Comment: i see your point i agree with you but @Red Viper count method returns 1 therefore code will always throw that exception if list is not initialized.

Comment: then to fix it you should add it to the answer how to fix check my answer above